# ZF2 ResultSet and count performance

Tags: php, database, zend-framework2

I'm using TableGateway with an attached custom RowGateway object. If I want to use the object returned by TableGateway->getSql()->select() to get a record count, the attached RowGateway object complains about a missing primary key in the result set.

```
   $tablegateway = new TableGateway('table', $adapter, new RowGatewayFeature(new AuditingRowGateway($primkey, 'table', $adapter), new ResultSet());
   $select = $tablegateway->getSql()->select();
   $select->columns(array('num' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('COUNT(*)')));
   $row = $tablegateway->selectWith($select)->current();
```

**Result: Zend\Db\RowGateway\Exception\RuntimeException: While processing primary key data, a known key xxx was not found in the data array**

I could work it around by issuing a normal (i.e. non-count) select:

```
$result = $tablegateway->selectWith($select);
$count = $result->count();
```

But not sure about this performance-wise compared to a 'SELECT COUNT(*)'.

Comment: Does you custom RowGateway extends Zend\Db\RowGateway\AbstractRowGateway?

Comment: Yes, but the problem also exists if I use the default RowGateway. I have found another workaround for now: I create two TableGateways of the same table, one for selecting and counting and one for writing, this latter one uses my AuditingRowGateway to record all changes.

Comment: Are you using RowGateway or TableGateway? Your example is confusing... looks like TableGateway NOT Row..

Comment: Added the TableGateway creation line to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you want just a count value, if include the primary key in the columns array, it should work.

```
$select->columns(array($primkey, 'num' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('COUNT(*)')));
```

Comment: It didn't work for me, but gave an idea. `$primkey => new\Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('COUNT(*)')` worked, however ugly it is.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:
`$select->columns(array( 'id'=>'id', 'nr'=>new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('COUNT(*)')));`